# Error after trying to build portaudio extension using cygwin

Tags: python, visual-studio, cygwin, pyaudio, portaudio

[image]
This error occurred after trying to install this version of pyaudio:https://github.com/intxcc/pyaudio_portaudio. First they asked me to install Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 and i installed it.After that this error is occurring.

Comment: First: do not attach picture. Copy and paste the log. Second: the instruction at https://github.com/intxcc/pyaudio_portaudio are or for Cygwin or for VS 2017. You are mixing the two tools; when buiding for Cygwin do not put your VS in the PATH

Comment: I didn't do it on purpose.How can i change my path?

Comment: To have a clean Cygwin PATH without any trace of the Windows PATH, just define the variable CYGWIN_NOWINPATH=YES in the Windows "System Variable" or "User Variable". Close all Cygwin processes and restart the shell.  The result is $ echo $PATH
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin 
The setting is in /etc/profile, if you are interested

Comment: I did that but when i typed `echo $PATH /usr/local/bin:/usr/bin` the output was
`C:/ProgramData/Anaconda3\Scripts/condabin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin /usr/local/bin:/usr/bin`.But when i typed python or python -i  cygwin didn't recongnized.So i guess it worked?

Comment: Comment formatting is poor. The command is just `echo $PATH` and the reply should be `/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin`.

Comment: same result ```$ echo $PATH
C:/ProgramData/Anaconda3\Scripts/condabin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin ```

Comment: check you cygwin HOME directory to find where the `C:/ProgramData/Anaconda3\Scripts/condabin` was added to one of the startup scripts. Probably `grep -H condabin .bash* .profile` will help you if the set is in the user startup scripts. Otherwise `cd /etc` and `grep -H condabin bash* profile` if the set is for all users.

Comment: Hi.I realized i didn't select to install python interpreter and setup.py when installing cygwin.Now i tried building the wheel again and no issues.